# NestJS: Handling Nested Body payload in PATCH having constructor in the DTO

Tags: typescript, nestjs

In my NestJS, I am having a DTO object like this:

```js
export class Protocol {
  public enabled?: boolean;
  public allowed?: boolean;
  constructor(enabled: boolean, allowed: boolean) { // It has a constructor
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.allowed = allowed;
  }
}
```

Now I want use this same Protocol inside one RequestDTO for my PATCH request. Something like this:

Controller:

```js
  modifySomething(@Param('id') id: string, @Param('uuid') uuid: string, @Body() body: ModifyRequest) {
    return this.service.modify(id, uuid, body);
  }
```

In my DTO (`ModifyRequest`):

```js
export class Protocol {
  public enabled?: boolean;
  public allowed?: boolean;
  constructor(enabled: boolean, allowed: boolean) { // It has a constructor
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.allowed = allowed;
  }
}

export class ModifyRequest {
  public name?: string;
  public nfs?: Protocol;
}
```

Now my question is:

How can I map the incoming request @Body to this DTO object correctly. These are the things I tried before posting here:

1. If I removed the constructor then it will work. However I can not remove it, as it has some other dependencies.
2. I also tried with `class-transformer` like this: `class-transformer` as follows:

```js
   import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
   export class ModifyRequest {
      public name?: string;
      @Type(()=>Protocol)
      public nfs?: Protocol;
   }
```

However it did not worked :(

Any help would be appreciated. I want to use the same `Protocol` in both the Response (which must have a constructor) as well as in the RequestDTO.

nestjs

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed it through `class-transformer`:

```js
   import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

   export class ModifyRequest {
      public name?: string;
      @Transform(({ value }) => {
         return new Protocol(value.enabled, value.allowed);
      })
      public nfs?: Protocol;
```

It worked.

Not sure if there is better trick to handle it through `class-transformer` without having a `new`. If anyone knows, please do let me know.